# Image aliased after rotation using camera object

Tags: android, android-canvas

I'm using the Camera object in android.graphics.Camera to rotate some images. The problem is after rotation, the edges of the image become aliased.
Is there any way I can apply anti-aliasing to the images before drawing to canvas.